# Are there any inherent limitations to the scipy.integrate.quad function?

Tags: python, gaussian, integral, quad

I am currently attempting to perform a definite integral of a gaussian function and I am receiving an answer of 0 when I am convinced that is not the case.

This leads me to ask, are there limitations on what exactly the quad function can do when performing definite integral? Am I using quad in the correct application? How exactly does quad find an integral anyway?

```
import math
from scipy.integrate import quad

def g(λ,a,u,o):
    return a*math.exp((λ-u)**2/(-2*o**2))

exc = quad(g, 4000, 8000, args=(1,6700,2.125))[0]

print(exc)
```

I have plotted this gaussian so I know that it is not zero within the range I have set. I have also plugged the integral in my scientific calculator and it spits out the answer of 5.33. So now I am at the conclusion that I have either made some mistake that I could not find or I am utilising quad in the wrong situation.

Any and all help is appreciated :)

Comment: Actually using `λ` as a variable name. Wow!

Answer (score 3):

Your function is basically 0 everywhere bar a small range, relative to the area you are trying to integrate over

[image: function]

You can add some points to help the function break the integration into smaller parts

> points(sequence of floats,ints), optional A sequence of break points
> in the bounded integration interval where local difficulties of the
> integrand may occur (e.g., singularities, discontinuities). The
> sequence does not have to be sorted. Note that this option cannot be
> used in conjunction with weight.

```
import math
from scipy.integrate import quad

def g(λ,a,u,o):
    return a*math.exp((λ-u)**2/(-2*o**2))

exc = quad(g, 4000, 8000, args=(1,6700,2.125), full_output=1, points=[6500, 7000])[0]

print(exc)

5.3265850835908095
```

[There seems to be no way around this problem](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/11571)

Comment: Thanks! I did not know the range relative to a thin peak like this is relevant. Figured the answer will be the same no matter the range as long as the peak is included. In this case, I can just shorten the integral area to 6500-7000 itself toget what I want. Thankyou for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Tom, the region where your function is significantly greater than 0 is too far out to be detected by the integration process. Theoretically, your `u` could also be `1e12`, but it's asked a bit much by an integration scheme to find that.

One easy remedy is to increase the quadrature domain to [-inf, +inf], and shift the function such that the "interesting" part is around 0.

```py
import math
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np

a = 1.0
u = 0.0
o = 2.125


def g(x):
    return a * math.exp(-(x - u) ** 2 / (2 * o ** 2))


exc = quad(g, -np.inf, +np.inf)[0]

print(exc)
```

```
5.326585083590876
```